# Insert with Entity Framework with SQL Compact 3.5

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, insert

I dont know why my sql request does not insert on database.

I think the db.Create(pers) does works.

```
private void SaveInsertAnim(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new DJURINGA_DIRECTOREntities())
    {
        PERSONNE pers = new PERSONNE();


        pers.NOM = textBox1.Text;
        pers.PRENOM = textBox2.Text;
        pers.ADRESSE = textBox9.Text;
        pers.CODEPORTE = textBox3.Text;
        pers.EMAIL = textBox4.Text;
        pers.TELEPHONE = textBox5.Text;
        pers.NUMSECU = textBox6.Text;
        pers.DATENAISSANCE = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text); 
        pers.LIEUNAISSANCE = textBox8.Text;
        pers.DATEDEBUTSEJOUR = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox2.Text)) pers.NOMBRESEMAINETRAVAILLE = int.Parse(comboBox2.Text);
        pers.REDUCTIONSNCF = textBox10.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox1.Text)) pers.NOMBREJOURPRECAMP = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);


         db.Create(pers);
         db.SaveChanges();


        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

My Functions Create() :

public static T Create(this ObjectContext context, T objetToCreate, bool save = false) where T : EntityObject
        {
            try
            {
                var type = context.GetSetBase(typeof(T));

```
            if (context.GetKeyName<T>().Count == 1)
            {
                context.SetValeurToKey(objetToCreate);
            }

            context.AddObject(type.Name, objetToCreate);
            if (save) context.SaveChanges();
            return objetToCreate;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas ?

i have no error, but nothing works ..

Answer (score 0):

Look for a copy of the database file in your bin/debug folder. Possible solutions: specify a full path to the database file in your connectionstring. Do not include the database file a content in your project